# Angular dynamically access to object properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I Need to access dynamically to different object properties in a loop but seems not valid.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in Items">
    <td>
        {{item.itemName}} <!-- OK -->
    </td>
    <td ng-repeat="monthName in months.monthName">
        <input class="form-control text-right"
               value="{{item.monthName}}" <!-- KO -->
               <!-- value="{{item.january}}"  OK -->
               >
    </td>                             
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) for this, i.e

```
  <input class="form-control text-right"
           value="{{item[monthName]}}"
```

I am not sure if your intention of using `value` is correct here or not, however if you mean to use ng-model then it would be:

```
  <input class="form-control text-right"
           ng-model="item[monthName]"
```

Otherwise you are referring to the property `monthName` of the object `item` and not the property with the name representing the value of `monthName` of the object `item`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the property called `monthName` of the object `item`.
If you want to use `monthName` as an identifier for retrieving something like `item.january` you can use the notation `item[monthName]`
The code will look like so

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in Items">
    <td>
        {{item.itemName}} <!-- OK -->
    </td>
    <td ng-repeat="monthName in months.monthName">
        <input class="form-control text-right"
               value="{{item[monthName]}}" <!-- OK -->
               >
    </td>                             
</tr>
```